# Best-Practice for organizing properties in a python class

Tags: python, properties, idioms

When using properties in a Python class, you have a lot of boilerplate code. Is there a best practice to hide the code for the getters and setters?

I know about `@dataclass`, but the problem is mainly with classes that are not data classes, where you have to scroll through the boilerplate code to get to the actual functions.

One idea would be to create the properties on a base class and then inherit from it to implement the functions. But I am not sure if this is clean code or if there are better design patterns for it.

Example:

```py
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._r = r

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @x.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value

    @property
    def r(self):
        return self._r

    # No setter for r. The circle can be moved but not resized.

    def draw(self):
        # Draw the circle using x, y, r
```

Comment: Is there an actual problem with having a `@dataclass` with behaviour as well as properties, or is it that you feel it is wrong to have a "data" class with behaviour?

Comment: Also, maybe because this is just a trivial example, but I don't see any advantage over using normal attributes here.  I get the sense you are coming at this from Java, C#, etc. perspective.

Comment: As your properties don't _do_ anything normal attribute access wouldn't, just _use normal attributes_. The benefit of properties is that you can introduce them when and if needed without changing the API. And @JimmyJames that's how type-annotating instance attributes works.

Comment: JimmyJames It's a minimal example to show how one must scroll through six methods to get to the actual code. In particular, some of the setters may not exist to protect the property from being set. I don't want to extend the example further, as it's not relevant what the properties might do for the problem that it's a lot of code that's rarely edited next to code that's under active development.

Comment: @allo I suggest using an actual example of a real problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @PhilipKendall The problem is, that I want to avoid these methods cluttering my code. Why I need the methods there is not relevant for the question. Let's just assume they are needed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I mean if there were default values set on those, they would matter but as written, they do nothing.

Comment: @JimmyJames yes I'm talking about the "class level variables", and no that's not incorrect. They don't do nothing, they set `__annotations__` to be used by type checkers like Mypy: https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations

Comment: @jonrsharpe It modifies the metadata but it has no impact on anything in the example shown.

Comment: OK now your example makes a little more sense, but you should probably show how `r` gets a value.

Comment: So, to be clear, are the getters and setters actually this trivial or is there more to them in practice?

Comment: I don't want to make the example too complicated, but the values could be initialized in the constructor and the storage may be more complicated than local variables. Depending on the answers, I may also look at alternatives like implementing `__getattr__`, but that would hide the interface and may be too generic for when there is a fixed set of properties anyway. In this question I would like to get feedback on the property approach, then I can still decide if another approach might be cleaner.

Comment: Related questions on SO: [Dataclass-style object with mutable and immutable properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532383/dataclass-style-object-with-mutable-and-immutable-properties/74032346#74032346), [How to make attribute in dataclass read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61237131/how-to-make-attribute-in-dataclass-read-only)

Answer (score 1):

*DISCLAIMER*

I do not want to present this as a best practice.  I don't even want to encourage this kind of thing.  For most projects, this is going to create a lot of confusion and it's definitely not what I would consider idiomatic.  To be clear, you almost surely don't actually want to do this.

*END DISCLAIMER*

Having said that, if you are truly in a situation where you have a large amount of boilerplate around properties and you can't use dataclasses or normal attributes, here's one technique that could be used instead.  I feel like there's probably different design approach to address this more properly but it's impossible to say without more detail.

In a nutshell, properties can be implemented programmatically.  The decorators are essentially short hand for the [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) built-in method.

```
def prop(name, readonly=False):
    def g(obj):
        return getattr(obj, f"_{name}")
    
    def s(obj, value):
        return setattr(obj, f"_{name}", value)
    
    if readonly:
        return property(g)
    else:
        return property(g, s)


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._r = r

    x = prop('x')
    y = prop('y')
    r = prop('r', True)

    def draw(self):
        print(f"Circle: ({self.x}, {self.y}), {self.r}")


circle = Circle(5, 5, 10)

circle.x = 50
circle.y = 20

circle.draw()

circle.r = 30
```

The only time I could really think something like this would be justified is if you a very large number of setters and getters where the only thing that changes in the body of each method is the name of the property or something where you can write a `prop` method as above which can implement many (dozens, hundreds) of such properties.

But most likely, people will hate you for doing things like this.  I expect to get some downvotes for even mentioning it.  But your question piqued my curiosity, and I learned a few things in the process, so I feel obligated to give you my findings in return.